# Notes by Bousfield

Tags: homotopy-theory, derived-functors

I am looking for a copy of "Operations on derived functors of non-additive functors" by Bousfield. It is referenced in many papers and is supposedly from 1967.

Obviously, and electronic copy would be preferable, but I am travelling a fair bit these days and might be up for the adventure.

Thanks.

PS, In case it helps, googling will give you several places where the paper is cited.

Comment: Have you asked Bousfield?

Comment: I know I have a copy on paper, somewhere.

Comment: @JimStasheff:Good suggestion! I figured it would be better to not bother him about it as I was hoping for an electronic copy which I guess he wouldn't need. I think I am incorrect in my reasoning though. Thanks for the nudge!

Comment: I know have the desired documents. If you would like a copy, please contact me. Thanks to all involved!

Comment: This does include "Homogeneous functors and their derived functors."